# Strange bibtex crash appcrash

Tags: bibtex

Today I encountered a very strange bibtex crash while writing on my thesis. The chapters are split up in separate tex files in a project. I am using TeXnicCenter 2.0 Beta 2 and MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7.

After adding another bibliography item and trying to produce the PDF file, bibtex crashed ("A fatal error occured"):

```
    Problem Event name: APPCRASH
    Application name: bibtex.exe
    Application version: 0.0.0.0
    Application Timestamp: 51c6159e
    Fault Module Name: StackHash_2353
    Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18247
    Fault Module Timestamp: 521eaf24
```

To test the bib file I already created a new tex file together with \nocite*{} and it worked fine without any errors or warnings. Finally, I figured out how the PDF is correctly produced without any errors: Quote some bibliography items. Thereby, it is irrelevant which one I quote. In fact, the number of bibliography items in the PDF must not be greater than 183.

However, processing all chapters at the same time results in aforementioned error. Nevertheless, a PDF file is created with the first 90 bibliography items. The bbl file also contains those entries, while the 91. entry is incomplete. The blg file is empty.

I also tried a reinstallation of MiKTeX as well as deleting all aux, bbl, ... files, but it didnt fix the problem yet.

The minimal working example (as well as the files it creates) can be found here: 
[MWE](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ujnr2r8slvg8iwn/AACEAcxfNql-FXr6I5ANurSsa?dl=0)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you remember which did bibiography item add you before of *fail*?

Comment: Consider use [biblatex](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf) and run with `biber` (`biber` is more stable and robust than `bibtex`). The *vancouver* style can be emulated in `biblatex` like is explained [here](https://github.com/fluffels/biblatex-vancouver/blob/master/import.tex).

Comment: The last ones I added were Frudakis2010 and Birenbaum2004. I never used biber so far, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: The MWE works fine using TeX Live 2014 (with updates) on Linux (x86-64). No crash, no incomplete entries in the `.bbl`, 185 bibliography items in the PDF.

Comment: Thanks for testing, mvkorpel. I tried the same tex file also on my laptop and it crashed. However, on the laptop of a friend it worked fine, too. Since I couldn't locate the error, I followed skpblack's suggestion and switched to biber which works fine for me now.